# Can I use a PayPal API to pay using a credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

As a developer and having a PayPal Business account can I pass a credit card payment, namely credit card number, name, CSV, to PayPal via an API rather than have a person manually entering the details every time ?

If so appreciate a pointer to where I can read more about this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

User Entering the credit card details for the 1st time , but subsequent times , the card details can be rememebered/stored and can be used by Store Credit Card feature in the REST API world.

More details : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/